# Android countdown not working

Tags: java, android, datetime, countdown, android-sdk-2.3

Trying to make a small countdown timer in my app but it's not working.

Idea is to count down to a specific time. First by days and when it gets closer, by hours.

The following method is inside my Fragmentclass.java (so it's a fragment)

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(2012, 8, 29, 10, 0);
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis(); 
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long remaining = currentTime - endTime;                 
        long seconds = remaining / 1000 % 60;               

         new CountDownTimer(seconds, 1000) {
             TextView tv = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.introTimeLeft);
             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                 cal.set(2012, 8, 29, 10, 0);
                long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis(); 
                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long remaining = currentTime - endTime;                 
                long hours = remaining / 3600000;
                long mins = remaining / 60000 % 60;
                long seconds = remaining / 1000 % 60;
                long days = hours / 24;
                String remainingText = String.valueOf(days) + " days";

                Log.i("countdown",String.valueOf(days));
                 tv.setText("Days left: " + days);
             }

             public void onFinish() {
                 Log.i("countdown","CD Finished");
                 tv.setText("CD Finished!");
             }
          }.start();
    }
```

Note that the textbox value is just for testing right now, but i can't seem to get it to display the countdown.

Also is this the best approach?

Comment: Is it not displaying anything? Or is it not counting down?

Comment: The textView.setText is not working at all. It doesn't update the control. Atleast its hitting the tick method thanks to Arhimed's post.

Comment: If you're displaying it in days, are you sure it isn't just displaying how many days are left? Is your Log.i call working (being called every time it ticks?)

Comment: you save my many hours.. I am confused with how to store countdown timer.. but your question give me answer.. this line save my many hours **long remaining = currentTime - endTime;**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the values of the variables if I run your code:

```
endTime     = 1348902045437
currentTime = 1340645325437
remaining   = -8256720000
seconds     = 0
```

as you see `seconds == 0`, and this is the reason.

Also note that the first argument in the `CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)` [constructor](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#CountDownTimer%28long,%20long%29) is

> The number of millis in the future from the call to start() until the
>   countdown is done and onFinish() is called.

So a fixed code would be:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2012, 8, 29, 10, 0);
long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis(); 
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long remaining = endTime - currentTime;

new CountDownTimer(remaining, 1000) {
...
```

**UPDATE:**

It is odd it does not update the text view. The only idea I can propose is to run update calls on the main UI thread. It should be something like this:

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    final String days = .. // some code to generate days
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            tv.setText("Days left: " + days);
        }
    });
}

public void onFinish() {
    Log.i("countdown","CD Finished");
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            tv.setText("CD Finished!");
        }
    });
}
```

If this doesn't help - then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Ok i see it, now its hitting the tick method. But it's not updating the text. I even removed the counter part and just added plain text. I also tried to move the textview variable outside the counter but that just causes a null-reference crash. So how can i update the textbox?

Comment: Works. Stupid Eclipse/Android/App.

Comment: Great! Well don't be upset, looks like you just need some time to read the Android docs/guide. Google provides nice documentaion, BTW, if compared to BlackBerry, for instance. However the combination of Eclipse and Android SDK can really bring some upsetting experience, that's true, it's not perfect.